# Max number Activities support in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, stack-overflow

I created an application with tab and many number of activities and child activities.But am getting an **StackoverFlow error**.Its because more number of layers of activity remaining in the stack.Now am planing it to rebuild with separate activities.Near to 30 activities will be needed for the app and I have also more functionalities in activities.So **I want to know is there any limit for the number of activities**.If  ***not*** will any thing happen to app if the the number of activities are more than 25 like memory issues and stackoverflow.if ***yes*** what is the limit of the number of activities in app.

> Looking for good advices

.Thanks in advance...

Comment: As i know there is no limit in number of activities, but more than 25 is really more..hope u gone through these questions too.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608347/max-number-of-activities
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717473/starting-too-many-activities

Comment: I find it hard to believe you are getting a StackOverflow due to the number of activities. This sounds more like an infinite loop in code somewhere. Post the stacktrace from your StackOverflow error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can have any number of activities, but good to limit max to 25 activities (as Google suggests). We can reduce number of activities by using Fragments. 
I hope this will help you.

Comment: Can you please share the link where you picked the 25 activities limit from?